# How can I print a Code-128 barcode with a TOposPosPrinter control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Please help!

I am trying to print a Code-128 barcode with the TOposPosPrinter control from CRM/RCS-Dayton.

While I do not have any problems to print plain text, printing the logo and cutting the paper, unfortunately the barcode is not working at all.

```
OPOSPOSPrinter1 := TOPOSPOSPrinter.Create(nil);
If IniOposLogoYn = true then printLogo;
OPOSPosPrinter1.Open(IniOposPrinterName);
OPOSPosPrinter1.AsyncMode := false;
OPOSPOSPrinter1.ClaimDevice(1000);
OPOSPOSPrinter1.DeviceEnabled := True;
OPOSPosPrinter1.PrintNormal(2, getWideString(BonTekst));
OPOSPosPrinter1.PrintBarCode(2, '12345678901234', 1, 500, 500, 1, 1);
OPOSPosPrinter1.CutPaper(100);
Sleep(50); 
OPOSPosPrinter1.DeviceEnabled := False;
OPOSPosPrinter1.ReleaseDevice;
OPOSPosPrinter1.Close;
OPOSPOSPrinter1.Free;
```

This is just a fragment of the code I am using, and everyting is working fine except the line with OPOSPosPrinter1.PrintBarCode...

I am using Delphi 7 for this application.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know the TOPOSPOSPrinter library. Can you debug it yourself to see what's going on? Can you ask the authors for help?

Comment: I tried, of course, but I cannot find the reason…

Comment: What does the documentation say about the meaning of the arguments for `PrintBarCode()`

Comment: This is the only documentation I can find, it's just the signature of the function:
    
function PrintBarCode(Station: Integer; const Data: WideString; Symbology: Integer; 
                          Height: Integer; Width: Integer; Alignment: Integer; TextPosition: Integer): Integer; safecall;

Comment: So, as it is a function, it might return an error code but you do not check the returned value! Is there a reason to request 500 as both height and width? Maybe 100 as height would be closer to what you need? (Just speculating as you have not explained any of your code). What is the make and model of the printer?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was nearby, just in de C++ headers...

```
OPOSPosPrinter1.PrintBarCode(2, '2420000004934', 110, 200, 200, -2, -13);
```

This line is doing exactly what I want... printing a CODE-128 barcode...

Comment: Good, but I still recommend that you check the return value of every call to the printer for eventual errors! Sometimes paper rolls come to an end, paper gets jammed, and what not.